# Making footnote numbering per-page when using acronym package

Tags: footnotes, acronyms

When I use the acronym package like this :

```
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
```

The footnotes are numbered across the whole document, which gets ugly when you have more than 10 acronyms in my opinion.

So apparently this is a problem with the footnote package, and there are some other footnote packages that allow per-page footnote numbering, but I don't know how to do this with the acronym package ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Please provide a \ac{MWE}.%
\footnote{Yes, a \acl{MWE}}

\newpage
Please provide a \ac{MWE}.%
\footnote{Yes, a \acl{MWE}}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{MWE}[MWE]{Minimal Working Example}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't think that the footmisc package would be able to replace the acronym commands. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Without [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) you could use the [`perpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/perpage) package and say `\MakePerPage{footnote}` (using @jon's nice example):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[footnote]{acronym}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\begin{document}

Please provide a \ac{MWE}.%
\footnote{Yes, a \acl{MWE}}

\newpage
Please provide a \ac{MWE}.%
\footnote{Yes, a \acl{MWE}}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{MWE}[MWE]{Minimal Working Example}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```